# pass array from php file to phtml?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email-templates, phtml

i use observer on order place . `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` when order is place i get order items and each item has a seller id . i get email from seller ids. 
and now send mail to those seller which has items in this order.

my observer code is

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $orderData=array();
            $order = $observer->getData('order');
            $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
            $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
            $orderData['customerName']=$order->getCustomerFirstname().' '.$order->getCustomerLastname();
            foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem){
                if ($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId() != ""){

                    $userdetail=$this->userFactory->create()->load($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId());
                    $orderData['SellerEmail']=$userdetail->getEmail();
                    $orderData['productinfo'][]=$quoteItem->getName();
                    $orderData['productinfo'][]=$quoteItem->getSku();
                    $orderData['productinfo'][]=$quoteItem->getQty();
                    $orderData['productinfo'][]=$quoteItem->getPrice();

                }
            }
            //$this->logger->info(print_r($orderData, true));

            $this->Seller_mail_method($orderData);

            return $this;
        }


public function Seller_mail_method($getOrderParams){
        /* Receiver Detail  */
        $receiverInfo = [
            'name' => 'Reciver Name',
            'email' => $getOrderParams['SellerEmail']
        ];

        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
         $TemplateParameter=[
           'customerName'=>$getOrderParams['customerName'],
           'orderItems'=>$getOrderParams['productinfo']
         ];

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            'seller_order_email_template'
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            ['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId()]
        )->addTo(
            $receiverInfo['email'], $receiverInfo['name']
        )->setTemplateVars(
            $TemplateParameter
        )->setFrom(
            'general'
        )->getTransport();

        try {
            // Send an email
            $transport->sendMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Write a log message whenever get errors
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

my `seller_email_template.html` code is

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans " <b>%customerName</b>," customerName=$customerName|row}}</p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>

            <table class="email-items">
                <tbody>
                {{layout handle="sellers_email_order_items"  area="frontend"}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

and phtml file code is

```
<?php

echo "testing";



?>
<?php //$_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($items): ?>
    <?php //$_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price') ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
       // Here want to set items
            <!--            <tr>-->
<!--                <td>-->
<!--                    --><?//= $item["product"]; ?>
<!--                </td>-->
<!--                <td>-->
<!--                    --><?//= $item["qty"]; ?>
<!--                </td>-->
<!--                <td>-->
<!--                    --><?//= $item["price"]; ?>
<!--                </td>-->
<!--            </tr>-->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">

        </tfoot>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can set $orderItems in phtm file ? my mail send correctly but now just set content.
please guide me .

there is problem in my code how can manage to set orderItems of same sellers. when call mail method these problem will resolve later . But now 1 order 1 item of 1 seller. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about the observer? Which event is used and the complete method. As far as I understand you want to pass data from that observer to the item renderer for transactional emails

Comment: @HelgeB ! i edit my question please review question if you understand .  please

Comment: i think may be session use here . to store orderitems in session and get session in phtml . is this suitable or other plz guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if you send the mail from your observer, it is possible to pass the object to the item renderer template. As far as I can see the passing to `seller_email_template.html` already works since you use `$customerName` , so you just have to pass the `$orderItems` to the item renderer block.

I guess with the following changes you should get the order items in your email:

seller_email_template.html:

```
{{layout handle="sellers_email_order_items"  orderItems=$orderItems area="frontend"}}
```

items.phtml:

```
<?php $items = $block->getOrderItems();?>
<?php if ($items): ?>
...
```

In your observer you should populate the array with the keys you want to access later in the template. I guess you should change the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem){
    if ($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId() != ""){
        $userdetail=$this->userFactory->create()->load($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId());
        $orderData['SellerEmail']=$userdetail->getEmail();
        $orderData['productinfo'][] = [
            'name' => $quoteItem->getName(),
            'sku' => $quoteItem->getSku(),
            'qty' => $quoteItem->getQty(),
            'price' => $quoteItem->getPrice()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try it  wait  . . . .

Comment: You have also an error where you populate the array, I have updated the answer regarding that error

Comment: HelgeB bro ! error in mail `Error filtering template: Codility\VendorOrder\Observer\OrderItemToOrder does not implement BlockInterface `
My `OderItemToOrder.php` is not implemented with block interface.

`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
        <block class="Codility\VendorOrder\Observer\OrderItemToOrder" name="seller_items_block" template="Codility_VendorOrder::email/SellerItems.phtml" />
    </body>`

Comment: my ` Codility\VendorOrder\Observer\OrderItemToOrder` in implemented with ObserverInterface. Thats why `<?php $items = $block->getOrderItems();?>` not work. 
how can do that

Comment: Then you need to create a block there you can't use an observer in the layout :-) Just create a simple block which extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and put that in your layout.

Comment: i send mail when order place. then how can avoid from observer ? 
or how pass orderItems from observer to block file ?

Comment: The observer is triggered by the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` and does not need any layout. You get the email template within your code and than you access the hanlde `sellers_email_order_items` which needs a block in the layout. For this layout handle you need to put a block in your layout not an observer class. Then all should work. You can try changing the class to `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` in your layout definition, that may already work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92189/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-helgeb).